# My ResultSet is only doing one row with .next(), but I do have 3

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
ResultSet chaserResults = LiteSQL.onQuery("SELECT count(*), id, name, geburt, geschlecht, speed, speedf, strength, strengthf, " +
                "val3, val3f, val4, val4f, val5, val5f, position FROM player WHERE position = 'Chaser' AND teamid = " + teamid);
        setchaser = new Chaser[chaserResults.getInt("count(*)")];
        int i = 0;
        while(chaserResults.next()){
            setchaser[i] = new Chaser(chaserResults.getInt("id"), chaserResults.getString("name"), chaserResults.getInt("geburt"),
                    teamResults.getInt("id"), chaserResults.getInt("geschlecht"), chaserResults.getInt("speed"),
                    chaserResults.getInt("speedf"), chaserResults.getInt("strength"), chaserResults.getInt("strengthf"),
                    chaserResults.getInt("val3"), chaserResults.getInt("val3f"), chaserResults.getInt("val4"),
                    chaserResults.getInt("val4f"), chaserResults.getInt("val5"), chaserResults.getInt("val5f"),
                    chaserResults.getString("position"));
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

I'm sorry for my bad coding!I don't really know why, but it stops after the first row. I think it could be the line "chaserResult.getInt("count(*)") thing, but I don't know how to replace it, because I need a method that counts the rows.

Comment: what is `teamResults.getInt("id")` ?

Comment: Also instead of an Array why not use an ArrayList?

Comment: You should learn to use parameterized queries, that's much safer, protecting against errors because wrong quoting and SQL injection vulnerabilities. Also when aggregating, all columns that aren't in the `GROUP BY` clause, should be an argument to an aggregation function. SQLite might accept that rule to be broken but most other DBMS don't. So the code is more portable when following standard rules. And the results might be funny either way when this rule is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `count(*)` in the result means that the query only returns 1 row.

Since [`count()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count) is an *aggregate function*, the query is an *aggregate query*, and as the [SQLite Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) says:

> If the SELECT statement is an *aggregate query without a GROUP BY* clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once for an **arbitrarily selected row** of the dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting entirely of NULL values.
>
> The single row of result-set data created by evaluating the aggregate and non-aggregate expressions in the result-set forms the result of an aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause. **An aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause always returns exactly one row of data, even if there are zero rows of input data.**